# D3: Multi-Series chart not working with last version

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I was trying to create a multi-series line chart and I found this useful example http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070069.

The problem is that is works good for the previous version of d3 (version 2) and some issues for the last version (version 3). After debugging that I found that the error was in the **transition** function of D3 when it tries to do `transition = node[ns][id0]` and `node[ns]` is undefined. I have this working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jupa_aguilar/0L1pyw8u/. I also observed that for d3.v2.js the `d3_selectionPrototype.transition` is:

```
d3_selectionPrototype.transition = function() {
var subgroups = [], subgroup, node;
for (var j = -1, m = this.length; ++j < m; ) {
  subgroups.push(subgroup = []);
  for (var group = this[j], i = -1, n = group.length; ++i < n; ) {
    subgroup.push((node = group[i]) ? {
      node: node,
      delay: d3_transitionDelay,
      duration: d3_transitionDuration
    } : null);
  }
}
return d3_transition(subgroups, d3_transitionId || ++d3_transitionNextId, Date.now());};
```

And for d3.v3.js :

```
d3_transitionPrototype.transition = function() {
var id0 = this.id, id1 = ++d3_transitionId, ns = this.namespace, subgroups = [], subgroup, group, node, transition;
for (var j = 0, m = this.length; j < m; j++) {
  subgroups.push(subgroup = []);
  for (var group = this[j], i = 0, n = group.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (node = group[i]) {
      transition = node[ns][id0];
      d3_transitionNode(node, i, ns, id1, {
        time: transition.time,
        ease: transition.ease,
        delay: transition.delay + transition.duration,
        duration: transition.duration
      });
    }
    subgroup.push(node);
  }
}
return d3_transition(subgroups, ns, id1);};
```

Any ideas about that?

Comment: That's some wild medley you put up in your fiddle! You inlined some code fragments of chart lineWithLegend belonging to a very, very old version of NVD3. The chart has been deprecated back in June 2012 and has since been removed from NVD3 altogether. This old version of NVD3 was based on D3 v2, which is why it worked in this kind of setup. I doubt, that it will be worthwhile trying to get this configuration to run. I recommend updating to the latest versions of D3 and NVD3 and start over from scratch. That will probably be much faster and save you from headaches.

Comment: That makes sense! I'm going to use the last version of each library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It better to start your code with D3 latest version.There were some changes in D3 latest version from it's last version.

So please check example with your comfortable version from internet and try to implement that rather than converting old version chart to new version by yourself.

if you want to see example,Visit this
[Multi Series Line chart with D3 V3](http://bl.ocks.org/Matthew-Weber/5645518)